# Is this operator bounded on $C([0,1])$ with the norm 1?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

I'm stuck on a simple exercise and I need your help to see how to resolve it:

Let $Tf=\int_0^1 x^2f(x)dx$
Let $Z=C([0,1])$ with the norm 1. Do we have $T:Z\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ bounded? Compute the norm of T if so.

Please I need help, I tried so many things, and I dont how to prove that the norm of $T$ is 1.

Thanks, 
Herosix

Comment: "I tried so many things" Excellent! Such as?

Comment: @Did If I remember, such as trying to find functions $f_n$ having the properties $||f_n||$ is less 1 and $||Tf|_n|$ going to 1 (I previously worked to show that it is easily less than 1), but these functions were never going to have $||Tf_n|| \rightarrow 1$ because each time it was going to 1/3 and the computation of the primitive was not a useful one. Anyway, I just didn't thought about using definition of the operator norm as the $sup$ of $\frac{||Tf||}{||f||}$ with $||f||$ less than 1.

Comment: Why aren't all these **in** the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$|Tf| = \left|\int_0^1 x^2f(x)\,dx\right| \le \int_0^1 |\underbrace{x^2}_{\le 1}\cdot f(x)|\,dx \le \int_0^1 |f(x)|\,dx = \|f\|_1$$

Thus, $\|T\| \le 1$.

Now define $f_n \in C[0,1]$ as $f_n(x) = x^n$, $x \in [0,1]$.

We have:

$$\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 x^n\,dx = \frac{1}{n+1}$$

$$Tf = \int_0^1 x^{n+2}\,dx = \frac{1}{n+3}$$

$$\|T\| \ge \frac{|Tf_n|}{\|f_n\|_1} = \frac{n+1}{n+3} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 1$$

Thus, $\|T\| = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer!